# jQuery script doesn't work when moved into a file with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

I have functioning `javascript` and `jQuery` files. I tried copying the `jQuery AJAX` into my other file, but It doesn't work. Instead of `AJAX`ing, it shows me the `JSON` info returned without the the template it was in. ?

View

```
def customer_profile(request, pk):
    name = get_object_or_404(CEName, id=pk)
    name_form = NameForm(instance=name)
    return render(
        request,
        'customer/customer_profile.html',
        {'name':name, 'NameForm': name_form}
    )


def update_profile(request, pk):
    if request.POST:
        name = get_object_or_404(CEName, id=pk)
        name_form = NameForm(data=request.POST, instance=name)
        if name_form.is_valid():
            name_form.save()
            updated_name = get_object_or_404(CEName, id=name.id)
            name_json = render_to_string(
                'ce_profiles/name_json.html',
                {'name_json': updated_name,}
            )
            return JsonResponse({'name_json': name_json})
```

templates

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
  {% include 'ce_profiles/name_header.html' %}
  <div id="name" class="container d-flex justify-content-between pt-1">
    <div id="name_json">
      {{ name }}
    </div>
    <button id="update_button" class="bold btn btn-main btn-sm button-main">UPDATE</button>
  </div>
  <div id="div_NameForm" class="container" style="display: none;">
    <hr size="3px">
    <form id="NameForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'customer:update-profile' name.id %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ NameForm.as_p }}
      <br>
      <button id="save_changes" type="submit" class="btn btn-main button-main btn-block">Save Changes</button>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
  <script src="{% static 'ce_profiles/ce_profiles.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'ce_profiles/ce_profiles_jquery.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

<div id="name_json">
  {{ name_json }}
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#NameForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      type: $(this).attr('method'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {$("#name_json").html(data.name_json)}
    });
  });
});
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#NameForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      type: $(this).attr('method'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {$("#name_json").html(data.name_json)}
    });
  });
});


let updateButton
let toggleNameForm = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  let x = document.getElementById("div_NameForm");
  let btn = this;
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    btn.innerHTML = "CANCEL";
    btn.classList.replace("button-main", "button-secondary");
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    btn.innerHTML = "UPDATE";
    btn.classList.replace("button-secondary", "button-main");
  }
};


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  updateButton = document.getElementById('update_button');
  updateButton.addEventListener('click', toggleNameForm);
});
```

When I delete the `script` link for `ce_profiles_jquery.js` and attempt to update the name displayed, all that shows in the browser is:
`name_json:  "<div id\"name_json\">\n The Name\n</div>"`

???

Comment: In the javascript part why are you using `$(document).ready(function() {` ?

Comment: I put that there just to show where I put the jQuery code. Am I not supposed to use that?

Comment: May be you should show the complete js code only without jquery to avoid confusion

Comment: Remove the jQuery. That's all I have so far.

Comment: Yes it was working correctly with 2 .js files. I replace the <div Id="json_name"> with another one in the success of the Ajax

Comment: I have set this up in a test environment and it is all working correctly. Note that you have included two `<div id="name_json">` tags in your example, but the second one won't be rendered because it is not within `{% block %}` tags.

Comment: With 1 js file or 2?

Comment: I used the 1 javascript file with your jquery code included at the top. If I comment out the jquery code, I get the same response as you have described, so something is stopping it from running correctly. Open up the javascript console in your browser and see if your code is throwing any errors.

Comment: Not throwing any errors, still doesn't work. @MattRowbum

Comment: Hmm. Can you open the page in your browser and view page source to ensure the jquery code is actually there? Find the appropriate `<script>` tag and click the source to view it.

Comment: Oh man. I forgot I copied the file from another location that has the same name. I was editing the wrong file and didn't realize it. @MattRowbum

Comment: :) I'll post an answer in case someone else comes across this issue in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the correct javascript file is being referenced in your template by checking the source in your browser.

I ran your code in a test environment and everything works correctly. When I commented out your jQuery code, the form submitted normally and the subsequent page displayed:

```
{name_json: "<div id=\"name_json\">The Name</div>"}
```

If you are not receiving any errors in your browser console, your reference to `{% static 'ce_profiles/ce_profiles.js' %}` is probably a different file without the jQuery code.